# How to change wordpress adminstrator user 's ID from 1 to 0?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a WordPress site with one user (ID : 0) (administrator). I would like to set this to 0. so my subscribers will have their IDs starting from 1 onwards.

I tried to change it manually from the wp_users table, but that didn't work and I had to restore the database for the user to be able to log in again.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL table that stores the user data `wp_users` have an autoincrement on the primary key `ID`. The database will handle it automatically to avoid duplicated values and the minimal value is `1`.

There is nothing you can do about it.
Here is the WP tables shema if you want to have a look https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users

There is no such thing as admin/client distinction in the user storage.
What you might want to do is create a new user for your admin (its ID would be `2`) and then rename the first user and set the right role for your client.
Of course, the next user will have ID `3` and so on...